# Setting JPanel image from file

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm working on a Yahtzee game and am having trouble loading a dice image for my dice.  I'm using NetBeans with the JFrame component, but would like to handle the file directly in my class as the image will need to change when the die is rolled.

Here's my code...that doesn't work...`

```
public class Die extends JPanel {

    //current number of die.  Starts with 1.
    private int number;
    //boolean showing whether user wants to roll this die
    private boolean userSelectToRoll;
    private Random generate;
    private boolean rolled;
    private Graphics2D g;
    private BufferedImage image;


    public Die() {
        this.userSelectToRoll = true;
        this.generate = new Random();
        this.rolled = false;
        try{
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("src/dice1.png"));
        }catch (IOException ex){
     //       System.out.println("Dice picture error");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}`
```

I've also tried using a jLabel icon and it also has not worked.  When I try to debug it, I get an error that says:

```
non-static method tostring() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

But I don't understand because I'm not calling a toString() method and I can't figure out what is.  I have used file images successfully in other programs but can not get this one to work!  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem, but you should read the image from a URL path for embedded resources

```
image = ImageIO.read(Die.class.getResource("dice.png"));
```

Notice how I don't need the `src` in the path.  Run the below code and see if it works for you. It works fine for me (given the path change)

And BTW, I don't get the error about the `toString` with your code. And use descriptive things like `ex.printStackTrace()` in your `catch` blocks so you can see what the actual exception is if one is thrown. Oh and use the `JPanel` and the `ImageObserver`, `this` in `drawImage`

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Die extends JPanel {

//current number of die.  Starts with 1.
    private int number;
//boolean showing whether user wants to roll this die
    private boolean userSelectToRoll;
    private Random generate;
    private boolean rolled;
    private Graphics2D g;
    private BufferedImage image;

    public Die() {
        this.userSelectToRoll = true;
        this.generate = new Random();
        this.rolled = false;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(Die.class.getResource("stackoverflow5.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new Die());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked!  I'm new at this so just trying out new things.